# No instance for Eq

Tags: haskell

I have a custom data type **Point Int Int** and I need to compare it to another **Point Int Int** (with elem function).
Could you please tell me how to write Eq instance for this data type? Thanks.

```
type Result = [String]

data Point = Point Int Int
-- missing Eq instance
data Line = Line Point Point

drawField :: [Point] -> (Int, Int) -> Result
drawField positions (width, height) = let
    check coordinates | elem coordinates positions = '#'
                      | otherwise = '.'
    in [[check (Point rows cols) | cols <- [0..width-1]] | rows <- [0..height-1]]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 8):

If two `Point`s are equal if all parameters are elementwise equal, then you can let Haskell derive the `Eq` instance with:

```
data Point = Point Int Int deriving Eq
```

If the points are equivalent if a more sophisticated test succeeds, you can define your own instance of `Eq` with:

```
instance Eq Point where
    Point xa ya == Point xb yb = …
```

where `…` is an expression with `Bool` as type.